# How to manipulate the cakePHP paginator

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3, pagination, cakephp-2.3

I have a Page with 80 Addresses and I want to set the addresses on a GoogleMap.
This runs very fine

```
foreach ($atlas as $atla): 
    $options = array(
    'title' => $atla['Atla']['name'],
    'lng' => $atla['Atla']['longitude'],
    'lat' => $atla['Atla']['latitude'],
    'content' => $atla['Atla']['name']
);
echo $this->GoogleMapV3->addMarker($options);

endforeach;
```

Thats my foreach for that Add option. Not so good for performance, but it has only 80 Addresses. And it's a Test.
CakePHP brings a paginator in Standardsetup, so that array is not the whole array with 80 Addresses.
How do i get the whole array in the view for showing, **without** shutting down the paginator?

If any can help me.

Many greetings
Marcus

Comment: Do you have control over the paginator itself? See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html for detailed information about how to control it

Comment: Yes i have control, but if i set the limit higher then we have less pages. I only want to change the array not the view. Is there any option for that?

Comment: I don't think that's possible using the paginator, it only queries the database for the records for a specific page. So if you set the limit to 20 it only queries the first 20 records

Comment: mmh not so good, thanks for answer Marcus

Comment: upgraded the comment to an answer

Answer (score 0):

The paginator queries the number of records set in the limit. So if you have 80 records in your database and have the paginator set to 20. It only queries the first 20 records from the database.

So you either have to set the limit of the paginator or use a different query to get all the records from the database.